# Add Prefix and page number in footnote citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I am new to LaTeX and I have a few issues with citing.
I want to have a footnote citation with the prefix "cf", then Names of the authors separated by commas, the year, and then page number with p. and a dot afterward. Example:
cf. Kaiser, Eckenbusch,2003, p. 29.

I used `\autocite{name_title-_year}`, which works fine but does not give me the prefix and page number. using bibtex and the following packages:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
```

I have already tried the things i found on this platform but they did not work:

```
\autocite{name_title-_year}\\
\citep{name_title-_year}\\
\autocite<⟨cf.⟩>{name_title-_year}
 \autocite{[name_title-_year}\\
\autocite{[cf.][post]name_title-_year},
(\citealt[cf.][p.~15]{name_title-_year}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The block

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
```

should be changed to

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Packages should only be loaded once, the package `cite` is incompatible with `biblatex` and `hyperref` should generally be loaded last.

With that sorted out, you can generate the desired citation output with

```
\autocite[Cf.][380]{sigfridsson}
```

that is to say `\autocite[<prenote, e.g. 'cf.'>][<postnote>]{<entrykey>}`.

If you want to get the commas as shown in the question, things will look like this

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[Cf.][380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}
dolor \autocite[Cf.][]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Cf. Sigfridsson, Ryde, 1998, p. 380.]